# Communication between C Server and C# Server just sending "p" character

Tags: c#, c, sockets, client-server, c-strings

I'm working on Client-Server application on Windows. Everything perfect running but when I want to send text (ex: Hello Dude) from C# client to C server then it send just "p" character. I dont know why? Thank you.

C# - Client Codes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ip, nick;
            int port;

            Console.Write("Nick Giriniz : ");
            nick = Console.ReadLine();
            Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            System.Net.IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.37");
            System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 5150);
            soc.Connect(remoteEP);

            NetworkStream ag = new NetworkStream(soc);
            BinaryReader okuyucu = new BinaryReader(ag);

            baslangic:
            byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi Dude");
            soc.Send(byData);

            Console.Write("Wait for answer");
            string reply = okuyucu.ReadString();
            Console.Write(reply );
            goto baslangic;
        }
    }
}
```

C - Server

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>


#define DEFAULT_PORT        5150
#define AZAMIUZUNLUK 1024

int g_port = DEFAULT_PORT;                  // Gelen Istekleri Dinleyecek Port
char g_szAddress[128];                      // Gelen Istekleri Dinleyecek Arayuz

DWORD WINAPI ClientThread(LPVOID lpParam)   //Dword = 32 bit isaretsiz tamsayi.
{
   SOCKET sock =(SOCKET)lpParam;
   int  ret;
   char gelenverix[512];
   char str[AZAMIUZUNLUK];
   for (;;) {
      ret = recv(sock, gelenverix, 512, 0);          //recv(socket,xxxxx, uzunluk, bayrak);
      if (ret == 0)
         break;
      if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Mesajlasma Sona Erdi\n", WSAGetLastError());
         break;
      }
      if (gelenverix == '\x1b')
         break;
      putchar(gelenverix);
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   WSADATA wsd;
   SOCKET sListen,sClient;
   int addrSize;
   HANDLE hThread;
   DWORD dwThreadId;
   struct sockaddr_in local, client;

   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsd) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup yuklemesi basarisiz!\n");
      return 1;
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup Yuklendi!\n");
   }

   sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
   if (sListen == SOCKET_ERROR) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Socket Baglantisi Basarisiz!\n", WSAGetLastError());
      return 1;
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Socket Baglantisi Basarili!\n", WSAGetLastError());
   }


   local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);   // ip adresimi kullan
   local.sin_family = AF_INET;                  // adres ailesi Arpa Internet protokolu
   local.sin_port = htons(g_port);              // default port numarasi

   if (bind(sListen, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
      fprintf(stderr, "bind() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
      return 1;
   }
   listen(sListen, 8);                          //8 - cagri kurugunda izin verilen baglanti sayisi

   for (;;) {
      addrSize = sizeof(client);
      sClient = accept(sListen, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &addrSize);
      if (sClient == INVALID_SOCKET) {
         fprintf(stderr, "accept() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
         break;
      }
      fprintf(stderr, "Accepted client: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));

      hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ClientThread, (LPVOID)sClient, 0, &dwThreadId);
      if (hThread == NULL) {
         fprintf(stderr, "CreateThread() failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
         break;
      }
      CloseHandle(hThread);
   }
   closesocket(sListen);

   WSACleanup();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug it? Does it work with a non-C# client? *Is* there a non-C# client? Is there a non-C server and does the C# client work with that? Work on narrowing the problem down. Step through things with a debugger so you can see what's going on. You're not going to get super great help by dumping the code to a couple of applications and the only information you give is "it only sends p".

Comment: `putchar(gelenverix)` should make your compiler yell in pain. Use `puts()` instead. Also make sure `gelenverix` is `0`-terminated beforehand. Or just do `for (size_t i = 0; i < ret; ++i) { putchar(gelenverix[i]); }`

Comment: As you said `putchar()` caused problem.. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`putchar(gelenverix)` should make your compiler yell in pain, as it expects a `char` and the code passes it a `char*`.

Use `puts()` instead. Also make sure `gelenverix` is `0`-terminated beforehand.

```
     ret = recv(sock, gelenverix, 512 - 1, 0); /* One less as you need space to 0-terminate the buffer. */
     if (ret == 0)
       break;
     if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
       ...
       break;
     }

     gelenverix[ret] = '\0'.

     puts(gelenverix);
```

Or just do

```
     for (size_t i = 0; i < ret; ++i) 
     { 
       putchar(gelenverix[i]); 
     }
```